# Sort ticket by priority, using customer satisfaction

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I need to make an algorithm that orders tickets in order of priority Normal or High according to the mood of the client, with 70% assertiveness. I have a JSON file with the tickets and their information, but I don't know how to do an algorithm that gives me this analysis. Has anyone done something similar?

```
{
 "TicketID": 28890,
 "CategoryID": 57526,
 "CustomerID": 97979,
 "CustomerName": "Cox Workman",
 "CustomerEmail": "cox.workman@email.com.br",
 "DateCreate": "2017-12-13 03:08:42",
 "DateUpdate": "2018-01-04 09:18:25",
 "Interactions": [
   {
     "Subject": "Without Subject",
     "Message": "I'm looking for men's shorts With side pockets 100 percent polyester.",
     "DateCreate": "2017-12-13 03:08:42",
     "Sender": "Customer"
   },
   {
     "Subject": "RE: Without Subject",
     "Message": "Hello! How are you? We don't have this model: / We have other models on the site, take a look.",
     "DateCreate": "2018-01-03 09:18:25",
     "Sender": "Expert"
   },
   {
     "Subject": "RE: Without Subject",
     "Message": "Thank you. GO shorts like with side pockets. Who made this model?",
     "DateCreate": "2018-01-04 09:18:25",
     "Sender": "Customer"
   }
 ]
```

}

This is an example of a ticket.

Comment: how is your data structured? it's hard to gauge importance just based on just the actual sentence that your user has given you. you could probably start with keywords like "please" or like "urgently" or a collection of those, but that would be slow if the tickets pile up. much butter to have some kind of category and subcategory of messages, like a dropdown type. then selection would be like "enquiry", "bug", "complaint", "feedback". then you would know what to prioritize

Comment: This is a big topic.  Google "Sentiment analysis" and go from there.